# grepping for multiple items

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have about 6 items I need extracted from and LDAP base dump file

```
fullName:
uid:
email:
...
```

the colon is required for the search, mainly because uid appears in a number of places in the file but the uid: is what I need.
I have tried to escape out the colon but any combination I use might upchuck the first search item, but not the second item. Then I have three or four more items to add to the list.

existing output:

```
gw1:~ # cat dump2.txt|awk "/email:/" && "/fullName:/"
-bash: /fullName:/: No such file or directory

gw1:~ # cat dump2.txt|grep -e "email:" -e "fullName:"
fullName: LDAP Proxy2
fullName: Student Email Administrator
fullName: Richard C. Holly
fullName: Jene E. Brown
```

expected output:

```
gw1:~ # cat dump2.txt|awk "/email\:/" print{','} && "/fullName\:/" print{','} && "/gid\:/"
email: proxy2@domain.com , fullName: LDAP Proxy2, gui: 987
```

Note the csv format.

Comment: You should probably use the `^` beginning-of-line anchor in your regex. I tend to use `sed -n /begin/,/end/p` for multiline matching, but it's not clear what the separator between records is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with a sample input file:

```
$ cat dump.txt
some: other
email: proxy2@domain.com
fullName: LDAP Proxy2
gui: 987
other: thing
```

To extract the desired lines and reformat them as CSV:

```
$ awk '/email:|fullName:|gui:/{s=s", "$0} END{print substr(s,3)}' dump.txt
email: proxy2@domain.com, fullName: LDAP Proxy2, gui: 987
```

How it works:

- `/email:|fullName:|gui:/{s=s", "$0}`

  This is a condition followed by a statement.  The condition is the regular expression `/email:|fullName:|gui:/` which is true only for lines that contain one of the strings that you are looking for.  In regular expressions, the `|` symbol means logical-or.

  If the condition is true, then the statement is executed.  The statement causes a comma, a space, the current line to be appended to the variable `s`.

  `awk` implicitly loops through all lines in the file and the above is performed on each line.
- `END{print substr(s,3)}`

  When we are done reading through the input file, we want to print all but the first two characters of `s`.  The first two characters are ", " which are superfluous.  The function `substr` is used to remove them.

#### Sample output

Using [the file that you supplied at `paste.ee`](http://paste.ee/p/BC6xk) and selecting for the fields that you specified in the comments ("mail:", "fullName", and "uid"), I obtain:

```
$ awk '/mail:|fullName:|uid:/{s=s", "$0} END{print substr(s,3)}' dump.txt
mail: pgroce@midland.edu, uid: pgroce, fullName: Patti K. Groce
```

All fields are found.

#### Input with blank fields

As per the comments, consider `dump3.txt` which has some blank entries at the end:

```
$ cat dump3.txt
other: thing
mail: pgroce@midland.edu
uid: pgroce
fullName: Patti K. Groce
mail:
mail:
Other: Thing
mail:
$ awk '/mail:|fullName:|uid:/{s=s", "$0} END{print substr(s,3)}' dump3.txt
mail: pgroce@midland.edu, uid: pgroce, fullName: Patti K. Groce, mail:, mail:, mail:
```

As you requested, the empty entries are printed as empty entries.

Comment: it still only prints out 2 out of 3 fields.  gw1:~ # awk '/email:|fullName:|uid:/{s=s", "$0} END{print substr(s,3)}' dump2.txt
uid: NFAUUser, uid: NFAUUser, DFS-Volume-Guid:: QORfRvqx1w, uid: LDAPProxy2, fullName: LDAP Proxy2, uid: nimspostmaster, fullName: Student Email Administrator, uid: rholly, fullName: Richard C. holly

Comment: also, to insert a new line, just include '\n' in the print?

Comment: @brad Hmmm. To make things perfectly clear, would you put (a) your sample input (the one which you said didn't work) and (b) your desired output into the question?  (Comments are quite poor for complex formatting.)

Comment: Sample data  http://paste.ee/p/BC6xk   Sample output is list above.

Comment: @brad Please clarify: (1) The desired output contains `gui: 987` but no such line appears in the `paste.ee` file, (2) The desired output contains "email: proxy2@domain.com" but the `paste.ee` file has no such line.  Did you mean "emailAddress:"?

Comment: notice my awk did not contain gui, that was just sample data. I will be collecting many different fields, not just the ones presented.

Comment: but I did try to gain email: and that field failed.  :(

Comment: @brad I cannot diagnose a problem that occurs for some input when you are not showing me that input.  The file at `paste.ee` does not contain `email:` and therefore will not produce `email:` in the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17569/discussion-between-brad-and-john1024).

Comment: The master file is just a bunch of objects just like the one posted. A new object for every person. You are correct, there is no email: but there is a mail: and your script misses that with ->   awk '/mail:|fullName:|uid:/{s=s", "$0} END{print substr(s,3)}' dump2.txt     Line 18 in the pastee

Comment: @brad I just tried it with the paste.ee file that you supplied and it works for me: the results are posted in the answer.  Are you running it on some "master file" that differs from what is posted at paste.ee?

Comment: What it is doing is, at the end of the query there are missing email addresses and instead of it writting the found value as a blank entry, it just failing to print mail: . Is it possible to print NULL returns?

Comment: @brad The paste.ee file has one _and only one_ `mail:` field.  That is why one and only one mail field prints out.  I added an example with multiple `mail:` fields, most of which were empty, to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the whole file into a Perl hash and print out the required fields (given as input arguments after the file name):

```
perl -nle '
    BEGIN{
        $input_file = shift;
        $required_fields = shift
    }
    my ($field,$val) = split/:/;
    next unless defined $field; #Skip lines with no field names
    $fields{$field} = $val;
    END{
        print join ",",@fields{split/,/,$required_fields}
    }' your_file 'email,fullName,gui'
```

Comment: I put your code into a .pl file and ran it with perl -nle and it just hung. http://sprunge.us/AagB

Comment: @brad That's because the code was never meant to be put into a file. Please try it: paste the above as-is on the command line (note that I have updated it to fix a minor bug) and if it works, I can modify it for you into a version that would fit in a file.

Comment: I did try that and it didn't work out to well  http://paste.ee/p/311yI

Comment: @brad As I've said, please take the extra comma I added into account: `print join ',',...`

Comment: same error with print join ',' as with  print join ',' ,

Comment: @brad Sorry, my bad. You need double quotes (`join ",",...`). Sorry, posted that late at night.